# Are fixed positioned images what I need?

Tags: html, css, position

Im having some issues with some fixed/absolute positioned images.

Please see the example for reference:
http://www.warface.co.uk/clients/warface.co.uk/

At the moment they are correctly positioned, but when the user clicks the red arrow box (top centre) you'll notice that the fixed positioned images are static and don't slide down the page as desired. Im sure they have to be positioned relative but they all seem to jump around when the browser is re-sized.

Any ideas on suggested methods are much appreciated :)

Many thanks

**CSS**

```
.minipeak {
    background: url("styles/images/home-peak2.png")no-repeat 0 0;
    width:206px;
    height:138px;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    top:288px;
    right:91%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
    }
.twinpeaks {
    background: url("styles/images/home-peaks.png")no-repeat 0 0;
    width:624px;
    height:349px;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    float:left;
    left:56%;
    top:220px;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.riflebg {
    background: url("styles/images/home-rifle2.png")no-repeat 0 0;
    width:254px;
    height:199px;
    display:block;
    top:110px;
    left:330px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    z-index: 1;
    }
.tank { 
    background: url("styles/images/home-tank.png")no-repeat 0 0;
    width:520px;
    height:285px;
    display:block;
    top:150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    right:-340px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    }
.snipers {
    background: url("styles/images/home-snipers.png")no-repeat 0 0;
    width:520px;
    height:285px;
    display:block;
    top:230px;
    right:66%;
    float:right;
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    }
.privatejoker {
    background: url("styles/images/home-privatejoker.png")no-repeat 0 0;
    width:421px;
    height:397px;
    display:block;
    top:80px;
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    z-index: 4;
    }
.rifle {
    background: url("styles/images/home-rifle.png")no-repeat 0 0;
    width:520px;
    height:285px;
    display:block;
    top:250px;
    left:330px;
    position: absolute;
    float:left;
    z-index: 5;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a parent container that wraps all your "main"-Content (snipers etc) and make it `position: relative;` (so all "absolute" childs refer to this as the anchor.

Use `position: absolute;` on all your elements (sniper etc) and tweak the positions via left/right/top/bottom OR (negative) margins to bring everything back to its position again.

Your "jump around" can be explained since you use relative values (percentages) in some places - these will depend on viewport size. Either you use constant pixel-values or you accept the fact, that most people won't resize the window while browsing your site.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'snipers' & 'twinpeaks' are outside of the wrapper hence why it did not slide together whenever you click to slide down.

Try putting it inside the wrapper along with the 'rifle', 'privatejoker' & such (^_^)